# Cloudformation Userdata not downloading libraries as intended

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created a cloudformation template, with a userdata section that installs conda, and uses conda to install a variety of other python libraries. However, after my ec2 instance is spun up, I checked the cloud-init-output.log file, and it shows that every bash command was executed. Despite this, the libraries still did not appear to be installed. Even conda was not installed, it seems.

Comment: FYI everything in userdata is run as the root user, in case that's relevant.

Comment: @jarmod Ok, so I don't even need to sudo su in my userdata section?

Comment: That’s correct, no need for sudo to root.